# How to set the space between two lines in Asana when pasting code in the description window?

Tags: formatting, asana

Asana offers rich text, a mode where you can add headers, change style, and if you press *Enter* without holding *Shift*, you will get a bigger space between the lines than with *Shift*. Here, you see how it looks without *Shift+Enter*:

[image]

And here is with *Shift+Enter* at each line break:

[image]

This works like anywhere else in rich text editors. That is all nice, until you want to just paste a code snippet and do not want to have such big space between the lines. You surely do not want to go through each row only to replace the *Enter* with a *Shift+Enter*. Instead, you would want to paste it with narrow spaces between the lines as a block.

How can that be done? Bonus question: is there perhaps a setting that allows toggling from *Shift+Enter* to *Enter* and back both when typing and when pasting? I could not find this in the Shortcuts at *Ctrl+/*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Types of Line Breaks

You are describing the difference between starting a new paragraph and starting a new line.

Typically this is referred to as some variation of `Hard Return` vs. `Soft Return` or `paragraph mark` vs `manual line break`, etc.

When you paste the code over, it contains the markdown code so what you are asking for is not going to be possible.  What other markdown should be automatically switched?  `Tabs` to `spaces`?  `Italics` for `Bold`?

The convention is typically to allow a user to strip out markdown (paste as plain text) and how breaks are interpreted would likely be as paragraph marks by default.

#### Workaround

Assuming the work of manually converting `paragraph marks` marks to `line breaks` is arduous because of the number of lines involved, you can leverage a secondary tool like MS Word and use their **Replace** to take care of the replacement:

1. Paste your code into MS Word
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> to bring up **advanced find**
3. Click on the **Replace** tab
4. put `^p` in **Find what**
5. put `^l` in **Replace with**
6. Click the **Replace All** button
7. Copy and paste the result into Asana

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a horribly easy workaround for this. Paste any code or text that should not have any markdown paragraphs in a comment box below the description box. Comments do not support markdown.

[image]